# Superscipt mathematical calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to calculate this in SQL Server.

Where c=85, z=4, d=6, and e=4

I tried this

```
select 85 / 4 * (6 * 4)
```

but looks like this is wrong any suggest please

[image: Formula]

Comment: note that the superscript means d 'to the power of' e - often denoted in computing as d^e, but not SQL where is is the power function (for some poorly thought out reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 85.0 / 4 * power(6,4)
```

slightly ambiguous formula, does it mean C divided by z then multiplied by d^e - anyway - use SQL x^y = POWER(x,y) and also put 85.0 to make sure floats are used

Comment: select 85.0 / 4 / power(6,4)  -- seems possible too - has the way calculation order is shown changed?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`POWER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) to handle the exponent:

```
SELECT 85.0 / (4 * POWER(6, 4))
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(85 AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) / (4 * POWER(6, 4))
```

Or in variable format:

```
SELECT c / (z * POWER(d, e))
```

Comment: Although I think you're possibly right that the formula writer meant it to be C / (zd^e) - your calculation gets the answer Zero though.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Could there be a casting issue?

Comment: there was previously when it had 85 / (4 * POWER(6,4)) where the values and operations get carried out as integers, causing 85 / {large number} to be zero.  A quick work around is to write the integers used with .0 after them.  I'd recommend casting to FLOAT in preference to DECIMAL for technical calculations